# Exporting interface from class .NET core

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code that was working Okay using .NET but when the code was ported to start using .NET core i'm no longer able to export the interface below with an the error

**The type or namespace name 'ExportAttribute' could not be found**

```
// Interface.cs
public interface IModule {
    string name {
        get;
    }
}

// TestModule.cs
[Export ( typeof ( IModule ) )]
public class TestModule : IModule {
}
```

What is wrong with the Export line? Is that not allowed in .NET core?

Comment: What is the full namespace of your `Export` attribute? Did you add reference to https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Composition.AttributedModel/?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ExportAttribute` is part of MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework). In full .NET it is contained in `System.ComponentModel.Composition` dll which is part of .NET framework itself.

In .NET Core it is contained in `System.Composition.AttributedModel` nuget package. So install [that nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Composition.AttributedModel/) and it will be available as `System.Composition.ExportAttribute`. Or better just install `System.Composition` package which contains above package as a dependency together with other necessary MEF classes (such as `CompositionHost`).